# Adjective after instead

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases

> The study described in the article shows that implementation of
>   dynamic LED boards doesn’t show a clear increase in traffic flow at
>   the bottleneck before congestions, probably because the LED displays
>   provide static information instead of dynamic.

Is this a proper way of using "instead of"?

Comment: Yes it is the proper way. You could substitute *as opposed to* if you wanted.

Comment: It's an odd sentence semantically though, because they are called "dynamic LED boards" in the first part, but then it says they only display static information in the second part.

Comment: @Jim I believe it uses "dynamic LED boards" to indicate that they are capable of showing various different displays, which once activated are then static. It's using *dynamic* in two different ways: the first might reasonably be replaced by "variable-message". [Not that that's relevant to "instead of".]

Comment: Then they should take out the first use of *dynamic*:  "that implementation of LED boards doesn't ..."

Comment: "implementation of dynamic LED boards doesn't **show** a clear increase" contains a poorly chosen verb. The implementation might **lead to** or **produce** an increase.  Better yet, change "increase" into a verb: "implementation of dynamic LED boards doesn't **increase** traffic flow".

Comment: @Jim I suspect that _dynamic LED boards_ is a common industry term for these electronic billboards.

Comment: @200_success While the word may be poor, I think it's a very common way to phrase the result of studies like this. I've seen similar language in reports on effectiveness of medical procedures, social programs, etc.

Comment: In fact, I think they go out of their way to avoid using words that imply causality, such as _lead to_ or _produce_, because of the well known fact that correlation does not imply causation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you cite has a lot of weaknesses, some of which have already been pointed out by commenters above. However, the issue you raise with "the LED displays provide static information instead of dynamic" involves phrasing that is neither ideal nor altogether indefensible.

The author may have struggled with not being free to use the relatively natural-sounding wording "the LED displays provide static instead of dynamic information." That wording is problematic in the example sentence because *static* can function either as a stand-alone noun or as an adjective, and the former would invite a misreading that the author wants to avoid. Compounding that problem is the author's unwillingness to repeat the word *information* at the end of the sentence—as "the LED displays provide static information instead of dynamic information"—which forces the reader to supply the implied final word, and which in any case sounds awkward and artificial.

As Andrew Leach points out, the example already uses the crucial word *dynamic* in two ways, without the least warning about the dual meanings. It also uses *shows/show* in two senses (neither of them particularly apt). And the phrase "traffic flow at the bottleneck before congestions" is ambiguous: Does it refer to a bottleneck in traffic flow prior to periods of major congestion, or does it refer to a bottleneck in traffic flow preceding areas of major congestion? I can't tell.

So it may be that your dissatisfaction with the handling of "instead of" is part of a cumulative negative reaction to a sentence that suffers from multiple annoying but not fatal flaws.

If I had been responsible for editing this sentence, I might have come up with something like this:

> According to the study described in the article, introducing LED boards that can display different messages didn’t significantly improve traffic flow at the bottleneck[s] prior to periods [*or* "at the bottlenecks preceding areas," *depending on what the author's original wording means*] of congestion. The explanation for this may be that the information on the LED displays is static rather than dynamic.

I chose to use "rather than" instead of "instead of" near the end of the example because it sounded slightly better to me, perhaps because "rather than" doesn't carry as strong a sense of "in place of" (as though the static information were replacing the dynamic information, rather than simply being an alternative to it); but if you set it up properly, there is nothing inherently wrong or awkward about ending a sentence with "instead of" plus an adjective, as in "static instead of dynamic."